# Why am I seeing different index behaviour between 2 seemingly identical CosmosDb Collections

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, query-performance, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to debug a very strange discrepency between 2 seperate cosmos db collection that on face value are configured the same.

We recently modified some code that executed the following query.

OLD QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE c.ProductId = "CODE" 
AND c.PartitionKey = "Manufacturer-GUID"
```

NEW QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE (c.ProductId = "CODE" OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.ProductIdentifiers, "CODE")) 
AND c.PartitionKey = "Manufacturer-GUID"
```

The introduction of that `Array_Contains` call in the production environment has tanked the performance of this query from ~3 RU/s ==> ~6000 RU/s. But only in the production environment.

And the cause seems to be that in Production, it's not hitting an index. See output below for the two environments.

**DEV CONFIGURATION**

Collection Scale: 2000 RU/s

Index Policy: (Notice the Exclude path for ETags)

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Spatial",
                    "dataType": "Point"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

**PROD CONFIGURATION**

Collection Scale: 10,000 RU/s

Index Policy: (Notice the absense of an Exclude path for ETags compared to DEV)

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Spatial",
                    "dataType": "Point"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

When comparing the Output results from both environments, DEV is showing an index hit, while PROD is showing an index miss, despite no noticeable difference between the index policies.

**Results in DEV**

```
Request Charge:           3.490 RUs
Showing Results:          1 - 1
Retrieved document count: 1
Retrieved document size:  3118 bytes
Output document count:    1
Output document size:     3167 bytes
Index hit document count: 1
```

**Results in PROD**

```
Request Charge:           6544.870 RUs
Showing Results:          1 - 1
Retrieved document count: 124199
Retrieved document size:  226072871 bytes
Output document count:    1
Output document size:     3167 bytes
Index hit document count: 0
```

The only thing I've been able to find online is a reference in the documents to some change that occurred within Cosmos Collection stating that a "New Index Layout" is being used for newer collections, but there's no other mention of Index Layouts as a concept that I can find anywhere in the docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-types#index-kind

Anyone got any idea where I can go from here in terms of debugging/addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dev container is newer and using our v2 Index which has significant improvements including on Array_Contains(). To learn more on how to upgrade your PROD container please email us at askcosmosdb at microsoft dot com.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer really needs updates: what exactly is this "v2" index? what are the "improvements"? How to upgrade? "Email us for help" is not really an answer.

Comment: How do we determine which version of the index our container is using?

Comment: Also that is not an "improvement", this is not faster; one works and one fails. I have a suspicion my newer collections fail on ETag comparison (AccessCondition if match).